# How does strlen function works in c?

Tags: arrays, c, strlen

The source code I found for `strlen` function in c is the one in below:

```c
int
strlen(string)
    char *string;       /* String whose length is wanted. */
{
    register char *p = string;

    while (1) {
    if (p[0] == 0) {
        return p - string;
    }
    if (p[1] == 0) {
        return p + 1 - string;
    }
    if (p[2] == 0) {
        return p + 2 - string;
    }
    if (p[3] == 0) {
        return p + 3 - string;
    }
    p += 4;
    }
}
```

The link is [this](http://beedub.com/Sprite093/src/lib/c/string/strlen.c). I don't understand why the steps are 4. The function jumps 4 bytes by 4 bytes over the string. Why it does this way? It could be implemented like this:

```c
int
strlen(string)
    char *string;       /* String whose length is wanted. */
{
    register char *p = string;

    while (1) {
    if (*p == 0)
        return p - string;
    p += 1;
    }
}
```

Is there any performance related reason behind it?

Comment: Well, for one thing it is using some ancient C syntax for parameters declaration. The first version has some attempt to manually unroll the loop.

Comment: It's probably an optimization thing. Assuming `string` starts at a 4-byte boundary (address ends in `0x...00`) loads to 32-bit register can happen in "larger chunks".

Comment: @EugeneSh.: You mean the _original_, K&R C syntax. Right?

Comment: @FredLarson Probably it is. What could be more ancient than that? :)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I'm feeling pretty ancient now.

Comment: @FredLarson lotta that going around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called "[loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)" and is done purely for performance reasons. Modern compilers are perfectly good at doing their own loop unrolling, so doing it manually is likely going to hurt performance relative to the compiler's generated code.